# Hadoop FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://<namenode public dns>:9000/input already exists

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce

I have Hadoop setup in fully distributed mode with one master and 3 slaves. I am trying to execute a jar file named `Tasks.jar` which is taking `arg[0]` as input directory and `arg[1]` as output directory.

In my hadoop environment, I have the input files in `/input` directory and there is no `/output` directory in my hadoop environment.

I checked the above by using the `hadoop fs -ls /` command

Now, when I try to execute my jar file by using the below command:

```
hadoop jar Tasks.jar ProgrammingAssigment/Tasks /input /output
```

I get the below exception:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-213:~$ hadoop jar Tasks.jar ProgrammingAssignment/Tasks /input /output
16/10/14 02:26:23 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ec2-52-55-2-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.5.213:8032
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://ec2-52-55-2-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/input already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at ProgrammingAssignment.Tasks.main(Tasks.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Source Code:

```
    public static void main(String []args)throws Exception{
    Configuration conf=new Configuration();
    Job wordCount=new Job(conf,"Word Count");
    wordCount.setJarByClass(Tasks.class); 
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(wordCount, new Path(args[0]));//input1
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(wordCount,new Path(args[1]));//output1 & input2
    //FileInputFormat.addInputPath(wordCount, new Path("/input"));
    //FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(wordCount,new Path("/output"));
    wordCount.setMapperClass(totalOccurenceMapper.class);
    wordCount.setReducerClass(totalOccurenceReducer.class);
    wordCount.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    wordCount.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    wordCount.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    wordCount.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
//  wordCount.waitForCompletion(true);
    System.exit(wordCount.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
```

If I hardcode the path where I have commented in the above code, I get the following output:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-213:~$ hadoop jar Tasks.jar ProgrammingAssignment/Tasks
```

16/10/14 15:51:19 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ec2-52-55-2-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.5.213:8032
16/10/14 15:51:20 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-52-55-2-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.5.213:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/10/14 15:51:21 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-52-55-2-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.5.213:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/10/14 15:51:22 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-52-55-2-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.5.213:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/10/14 15:51:23 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-52-55-2-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.5.213:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)

Answer (score 1):

When you run the following command:

```
hadoop jar Tasks.jar ProgrammingAssigment/Tasks /input /output
```

The args array will contain the following elements:

```
args[0]     ProgrammingAssigment/Tasks
args[1]     /input
args[2]     /output
```

Try omitting the `ProgrammingAssigment/Tasks` parameter, my guess is that it is not needed. If it is needed for some reason, then use `args[1]` and `args[2]` in your code for the input and output directories, respectively.

Regarding the timeout you get, I have no idea. You could try increasing the maxRetries or sleepTime values that it mentions.